# SQL SELECT statement does not scan the entire table (10,000 rows)

Tags: php, sql, json

**My task:**

I have a table of products from the online shop, (10,000+ products). When a user starts typing in the brand in the search box he must get the suggested brands that correspond to his input.

Example: typing in: "a", suggested result: "Adidas", "AG Jeans", . . . etc

**My implementation**

I use Ajax to send requests for a PHP script every time a user presses the key on the keyboard. The PHP script does this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `Vendor` FROM `catalog_farfetch` WHERE `Vendor` LIKE '%".$brand_like."%'
```

The result gets returned in the form of a JSON array simply like this:

```
exit(json_encode($suggestions));
```

where $suggestions is an array

**My problem**
I get only a little part of what I actually should get. I feel like only 10% of the table gets scanned. For example, if I enter "n", then I don't get any brand starting with "n" like Nike. I came to the conclusion that the query does not go further than about 200 rows. If I enter full "Nike", then it finds it perfectly.

**Conclusion**
I think there must be something like SQL limitation that does not allow checking so many rows at once. Or maybe PHP does not allow such long queries? Or maybe I cannot return such a long JSON object?...

Thank you!

Comment: n is not the same as N. Lowercase and uppercase. Try to LOWER or UPPER both `Vendor` and your search query

Comment: Is your table collation case insensitive? (ends with `_ci`)? Have you tried that query manually? Maybe some framework adds default limitation?

Comment: _"For example, if I enter 'n', then I don't get any brand starting with 'n' like Nike."_ Your query doesn't look for vendors _starting_ with N, it looks for vendors _containing_ an N. Take the `%` off the start of your like.

Comment: @AlexHowansky In your example it looks for records containing `n` not `N`.

Comment: @AlexHowansky `%` matches 0 or more symbols, so `%n%` would match `Nike`

Comment: @Justinas Yes, but it would also match a lot of other things that would appear in the list before Nike, possibly making OP think it wasn't included.

Comment: *The PHP script does this query `'%".$brand_like."%'`* - this is probably the number one most foolish thing you can do when creating a website; http://bobby-tables.com

Comment: @Daan thanks for the reply. But my query is case insensitive, sorry for not mentioning that.